# Change image src for visited link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, visited

I have a list with several entries.

```
<ul>    
<li>
    <a href="http://url" title="The Title">
    <img src="/badge-unvisited.png" alt="" border="0" />
    </a>
</li>
<!-- etc. -->
</ul>
```

I don't want to use jQuery, so it needs to be CSS-only.
What is the best and easiest way to change the src of the image when it was visited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, you can't change the image src just with css.

But you could just make it a background-image of a same-sized  and then use the :hover class like

```
div {
    background-image:url(default.jpg);
}

div:visited {
    background-image:url(changed.jpg);
}
```

Btw an even niftier solution would be to use the same image including both states and just changing the `background-position`. That way there's less load. Look for 'css sprites' if you are interested in more!

Comment: The problem is that having a div inside of an anchor element ("a") is not valid. I could use the li element and give it a background. But I can't wrap the link around the li. So what element would I use? A span with display:block is the only option I see.

Comment: HTML5 allows block elements in <a>. Otherwise the span with display:block would be the next best solution, yes !

Answer (score 4):

> What is the best and easiest way to change the src of the image when it was visited?

There is none. The `src` property of an image is out of scope for CSS.

You will have to work with `background-image` properties instead.

You could theoretically have two images and show one at one time, and the other at the next using `display: none`, but that is pretty kludgy and causes both images to be loaded.

Answer (score 3):

At least in Webkit and Firefox this is not possible, since styling of visited links allows for various attack scenarios.

http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=147777
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24300

Answer (score 2):

You can alter properties for the image like this:

`ul li a:visited img { border:10px }`

But to change the source itself you have to get creative. either replace the image with a element having a background image or, if you don't have to support older browsers you could use generated content, like this:

`ul li a:after { content:url(image.gif); }`

and then

`ul li a:visited:after { content:url(image-2.gif); }`

Answer (score 1):

css can't modify the dom, what I could suggest is setting a background image, and then hiding the img

```
a{background-image:url(badge-visited.png);width:50px;height:50px;}
a:visited img{display:none;}
```

Comment: good idea! although <a> is an inline element and won't take width and height. you could just make it a block element with display:block;